# Project Ideas Mixing Chemistry with CS

Tags: computational-chemistry

I'm a high-school senior who has just taken the AP Chemistry exam and my teacher has just assigned me an end-of-year project exploring whatever aspect of Chemistry I want. I really enjoy computer programming as well (took the AP last year) and do it a significant amount in my free time, so I was considering finding a Chemistry project that involves some coding or computer modeling (or anything having to do with computers). Could anybody recommend some topics to check out? (I looked at molecular dynamics simulations, but a lot of that stuff contains multivariable calc./quantum mechanics, which might be a bit much).

Comment: Computational chemistry is pretty complicated. Even the classical stuff like MD or Force Fields might be too big a bite for your project. (I'll think about it a bit and maybe write an answer later)

Comment: As far as programming goes, Monte Carlo algorithms use fairly simple codes. Perhaps someone could design simple studies of finding equilibrium bond lengths in different diatomic molecules using a very simple force field. In such molecules, the only geometrical parameter to vary is the internuclear separation, so a Lennard-Jones potential could be used to find the most stable internuclear distance. This should be easily done in matlab, but I suppose you could use a range of different languages.

Comment: This seems like a "[shopping question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/305499)", which aren't a good fit for this site. If you have specific questions on computational chemistry, we can possibly answer those, but solicitations of a list of suggestions here is a little too broad.

Comment: If you want to learn something about quantum mechanics, simple model systems one could play around with are the Particle-in-a-Box or Hückel MO Theory. Nice applications are always calculating HOMO-LUMO gaps for dyes, although they do not perform very good.

Comment: R.M. is right, since there is no correct answer to this. But I think it's great that you want to learn more about computational chemistry! I'd be happy to be of whatever help I may be in brainstorming via e-mail or something.

Comment: Regarding MD, you can go pretty far with just a simple Verlet algorithm.

Comment: It's probably best in your case to use an already existing software and show a variety of results from the program with some description of how it works and what the results mean. As a shameless plug I'll share with you the code I've been working on for ~4 years in grad school, MCMD. It works on Mac and Linux; not tested on Windows. If you have questions about how to use and interpreting results feel free to get in touch. https://github.com/khavernathy/mcmd

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions — would it be possible to write a really simple modeler where you start with two atoms/ions (can customize each to any of a number of elements) and start a timer which shows how they interact and, if they attract, the lowest potential energy state/distance they come to?

Comment: These exercises (written in Latex)  take you through writing a simple MD program.  There's some python intro at the beginning of each exercise that you can skip https://github.com/jensengroup/molstat/tree/master/handout